# g++ removes useless function? Undefined reference

Tags: c++, g++, makefile, ld

I have hpp file with declaration:

```
namespace X {
    class Y {
        public:
          [other functions]

          inline float basicFunction();
          int someFunction();

        [other functions]
    };
}
```

And in cpp file:

```
namespace X { 
    [implementations etc.]

    inline float Y::basicFunction() {
        return someValue * someMath / moreMath;
    }

    int Y::someFunction() {
        return basicFunction() * 100;
    }

    [other functions]
}
```

I'm using it at other cpp file, but I think this isn't problem. Compiling with:

```
g++ -c someclass.cpp -o someclass.o -std=c++11
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o -std=c++11
g++ main.o someclass.o -o main -std=c++11 -O0
```

Throw error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
    main.cpp:(.text+0x4d9): undefined reference to `X::Y::someFunction()'
```

Why? How I can compile it correct?
I know that `someFunction()` is useless, but this is called many times and I just like that way.

*All code above isn't real, so may have bugs, but on my program it's (I think) correct*

I tried many combinations (both functions with same return type, both inline, none inline etc.) and no effect.

Comment: Why is `Y::basicFunction()` inline in your CPP file?

Comment: What does the calling code in `main` look like?

Comment: Do your real compile commands output `someclass.o` and `main.o`, not `someclass` and `main`?

Comment: And for the record, we honestly don't care if the code is real or not, so long as it (a) **compiles**, and (b) **reproduces the problem**.

Comment: @WhozCraig - this must be declared inline only in HPP? Nevermind, now I removed inline and problem still exist. Code in post can't be compiled, for obvious reason ;)
@ChrisMantle - just creating object `X::Y obj` and `obj.function()`
@MikeSeymour - yes (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Function cannot be inline.

Still don't know why it worked after some attempts after deleted inline but nevermind.

Explanation why function in this code can't be inline is simple. Compiler, when see "inline", don't create pointer to function, but paste code in the place of reference.

Just my mistake...